# Android emulator browser crash

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-emulator

I'm trying to use the browser in android sdk emulator (mac) but it keeps crashing after opening. As long as I use 4.4. I'm not even able to enter a URL. Are there some logs I could check to find out what's wrong? I've tried it on two machines, both share the same error.

Here the init log:

```
emulator -avd AVD_for_Nexus_S_by_Google -debug-init
emulator: found SDK root at /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/22.3
emulator: Android virtual device file at: /Users/tobi/.android/avd/AVD_for_Nexus_S_by_Google.ini
emulator: virtual device content at /Users/tobi/.android/avd/AVD_for_Nexus_S_by_Google.avd
emulator: virtual device config file: /Users/tobi/.android/avd/AVD_for_Nexus_S_by_Google.avd/config.ini
emulator: using core hw config path: /Users/tobi/.android/avd/AVD_for_Nexus_S_by_Google.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: Found AVD target API level: 19
emulator: 'magic' skin format detected: 480x800
emulator: autoconfig: -skin 480x800
emulator: autoconfig: -skindir (null)
emulator: keyset loaded from: /Users/tobi/.android/default.keyset
emulator: found SDK root at /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/22.3
emulator: trying to load skin file '/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/22.3/tools/lib/emulator/skins/dynamic//layout'
emulator: loaded dynamic skin width=480 height=800 bpp=16

emulator: autoconfig: -kernel /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/22.3/system-images/android-19/armeabi-v7a//kernel-qemu
emulator: autoconfig: -ramdisk /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/22.3/system-images/android-19/armeabi-v7a//ramdisk.img
emulator: Using initial system image: /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/22.3/system-images/android-19/armeabi-v7a//system.img
emulator: autoconfig: -data /Users/tobi/.android/avd/AVD_for_Nexus_S_by_Google.avd/userdata-qemu.img
emulator: autoconfig: -initdata /Users/tobi/.android/avd/AVD_for_Nexus_S_by_Google.avd/userdata.img
emulator: autoconfig: -cache /Users/tobi/.android/avd/AVD_for_Nexus_S_by_Google.avd/cache.img
emulator: Physical RAM size: 343MB

Content of hardware configuration file:
  hw.cpu.arch = arm
  hw.cpu.model = cortex-a8
  hw.ramSize = 343
  hw.screen = touch
  hw.mainKeys = yes
  hw.trackBall = no
  hw.keyboard = yes
  hw.keyboard.lid = no
  hw.keyboard.charmap = qwerty2
  hw.dPad = no
  hw.gsmModem = yes
  hw.gps = yes
  hw.battery = no
  hw.accelerometer = yes
  hw.audioInput = yes
  hw.audioOutput = yes
  hw.sdCard = yes
  disk.cachePartition = yes
  disk.cachePartition.path = /Users/tobi/.android/avd/AVD_for_Nexus_S_by_Google.avd/cache.img
  disk.cachePartition.size = 66m
  hw.lcd.width = 480
  hw.lcd.height = 800
  hw.lcd.depth = 16
  hw.lcd.density = 240
  hw.lcd.backlight = yes
  hw.gpu.enabled = no
  hw.camera.back = none
  hw.camera.front = none
  vm.heapSize = 32
  hw.sensors.proximity = yes
  hw.sensors.magnetic_field = yes
  hw.sensors.orientation = yes
  hw.sensors.temperature = yes
  hw.useext4 = yes
  kernel.path = /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/22.3/system-images/android-19/armeabi-v7a//kernel-qemu
  kernel.parameters =  android.checkjni=1
  disk.ramdisk.path = /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/22.3/system-images/android-19/armeabi-v7a//ramdisk.img
  disk.systemPartition.initPath = /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/22.3/system-images/android-19/armeabi-v7a//system.img
  disk.systemPartition.size = 550m
  disk.dataPartition.path = /Users/tobi/.android/avd/AVD_for_Nexus_S_by_Google.avd/userdata-qemu.img
  disk.dataPartition.size = 200m
  avd.name = AVD_for_Nexus_S_by_Google
.
QEMU options list:
emulator: argv[00] = "/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/22.3/tools/emulator64-arm"
emulator: argv[01] = "-android-hw"
emulator: argv[02] = "/Users/tobi/.android/avd/AVD_for_Nexus_S_by_Google.avd/hardware-qemu.ini"
Concatenated QEMU options:
 /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/22.3/tools/emulator64-arm -android-hw /Users/tobi/.android/avd/AVD_for_Nexus_S_by_Google.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: nand_add_dev: system,size=0x22600000,initfile=/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/22.3/system-images/android-19/armeabi-v7a//system.img,pagesize=512,extrasize=0
emulator: mapping 'system' NAND image to /tmp/android-tobi/emulator-lSd528
emulator: nand_add_dev: userdata,size=0xc800000,file=/Users/tobi/.android/avd/AVD_for_Nexus_S_by_Google.avd/userdata-qemu.img,pagesize=512,extrasize=0
emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: Adding boot property: 'dalvik.vm.heapsize' = '32m'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.lcd_density' = '240'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.hw.mainkeys' = '1'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.fake_camera' = 'none'
emulator: nand_add_dev: cache,size=0x4200000,file=/Users/tobi/.android/avd/AVD_for_Nexus_S_by_Google.avd/cache.img,pagesize=512,extrasize=0
emulator: Initializing hardware OpenGLES emulation support
emulator: Kernel parameters: qemu.gles=0 qemu=1 console=ttyS0 android.qemud=ttyS1 android.checkjni=1 ndns=1
emulator: Trace file name is not set

emulator: autoconfig: -scale 1
emulator: Could not open file: (null)/system/build.prop: No such file or directory
emulator: control console listening on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
emulator: sent '0012host:emulator:5555' to ADB server
emulator: ping program: /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/22.3/tools/ddms
emulator: ping command: /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/22.3/tools/ddms ping emulator 22.3.0 "Intel Inc." "Intel HD Graphics 5000 OpenGL Engine" "2.1 INTEL-8.18.26"
goldfish_fb_get_pixel_format:167: display surface,pixel format:
  bits/pixel:  16
  bytes/pixel: 2
  depth:       16
  red:         bits=5 mask=0xf800 shift=11 max=0x1f
  green:       bits=6 mask=0x7e0 shift=5 max=0x3f
  blue:        bits=5 mask=0x1f shift=0 max=0x1f
  alpha:       bits=0 mask=0x0 shift=0 max=0x0
```

Comment: Is the browser 'Android  browser' (blue globe icon) or Google Chrome for Android (which isn't installed by default?).

Answer (score 31):

I had this issue on an Android 6.0 Emulator until I updated the permissions for the browser to allow access to storage, this solved the problem for me.

in the emulator, navigate to: Settings -> Apps -> Browser and select Permissions, then enable storage.

Answer (score 10):

Launching emulator with `feature` `Vulkan` flag worked for me:

`emulator.exe -avd 'YOUR_EMULATOR_NAME' -feature -Vulkan`

Comment: This is the solution for me. Using MacOS 14, arch arm64 (M1) and emulating a device with API 34 (installed with Android Studio). Things are also running faster and without graphic glitchs until now.

Comment: My life saver!!

Answer (score 7):

I solved this issue on AOSP by creating a new sdcard.img:

```
mksdcard 1G out/target/product/generic/sdcard.img
```

Then launch the emulator with:

```
emulator -sdcard out/target/product/generic/sdcard.img
```

For the SDK try creating another sdcard manually or through the GUI.

Answer (score 4):

I could solve this issue by just specifying SD Card Size for the AVD

Answer (score 1):

Well, after struggling for a few days with the issue, and after trying all the possible solutions like setting the DNS servers, pressing the F8 key, my issue was resolved by creating an SD Image file, per the solution given by user1895218 above. I am running 32 bit Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

This was identified by looking at the logcat message below:

**E/NativeDaemonConnector.ResponseQueue(  364): Timeout waiting for response**

E/VoldConnector(  364): timed-out waiting for response to 3 volume mkdirs /storage/sdcard/Android/data/com.android.browser/files/

D/AndroidRuntime(  832): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(  832): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1a47b90)

E/AndroidRuntime(  832): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(  832): Process: com.android.browser, PID: 832
E/AndroidRuntime(  832): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.android.browser.provider.SnapshotProvider: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(  832):    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4774)
E/AndroidRuntime(  832):    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4366)
E/AndroidRuntime(  832):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4306)
E/AndroidRuntime(  832):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime(  832):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1457)
E/AndroidRuntime(  832):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime(  832):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(  832):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
E/AndroidRuntime(  832):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  832):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime(  832):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
E/AndroidRuntime(  832):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
E/AndroidRuntime(  832):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  832): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(  832):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1467)
E/AndroidRuntime(  832):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1415)
E/AndroidRuntime(  832):    at android.os.storage.IMountService$Stub$Proxy.mkdirs(IMountService.java:750)
E/AndroidRuntime(  832):    at android.app.ContextImpl.ensureDirsExistOrFilter(ContextImpl.java:2160)
E/AndroidRuntime(  832):    at android.app.ContextImpl.getExternalFilesDirs(ContextImpl.java:856)
E/AndroidRuntime(  832):    at android.app.ContextImpl.getExternalFilesDir(ContextImpl.java:839)
E/AndroidRuntime(  832):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getExternalFilesDir(ContextWrapper.java:210)
E/AndroidRuntime(  832):    at com.android.browser.provider.SnapshotProvider.getOldDatabasePath(SnapshotProvider.java:116)
E/AndroidRuntime(  832):    at com.android.browser.provider.SnapshotProvider.migrateToDataFolder(SnapshotProvider.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(  832):    at com.android.browser.provider.SnapshotProvider.onCreate(SnapshotProvider.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(  832):    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1589)
E/AndroidRuntime(  832):    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1560)
E/AndroidRuntime(  832):    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4771)
E/AndroidRuntime(  832):    ... 12 more

Comment: An SD image file of what? Do you mean that there must be a validly formatted SD card in the virtual slot?

Comment: I'll answer my own question, yes there must be a valid SD card image in the virtual slot. Under Windows you can find this in <adt>\sdk\tools and use this command line to make a small one just to make the emulator behave itself: mksdcard -l 64M 64M 64M_SD.img

Comment: And how do you cope with emulator beiing incrediblly slow? I mean, boot takes about an hour. Each press on the "screen" take about 5-10 minutes for response.